# How to fix linker error when working with openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, linker

Im trying to set up openCV on my mac and work with it in Eclipse with C++.
But I think somthing is wrong with the linker.
I included all libraries as described here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html

I tried the linker commands `g++` and `g++ -std=c++11` but get always the same error message:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o camera src/Camera.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -
lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Camera.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

for the following code:

```
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.hpp"
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if that is opencv3.0, you will need -lopencv_imgcodecs for imread(). also, please do not use absolute path, but `#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`imread` has been moved in the opencv_imgcodecs library.

Try to add -lopencv_imgcodecs to your linker flags.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed this one!